# hg actions appear to abort on FreeBSD VM: wcache owned by root

Tags: freebsd, chroot, mercurial

I am running a FreeBSD 11.2-RELEASE-p14 build server as a headless VM using virtual box.
I ssh -Y into a terminal session.

I'm using mercurial version 5.1.1

When I do hg actions, I often get an error message of this form:

abort: Permission denied: '/stg/cgrandits/rel-unicorn/Release/unicorn/chroot/tsc/sources/devel/.hg/wcache/.manifestfulltextcache-14uv9W~'

note the repo is in a chroot environment, that may be a contributing factor?

When I subsequently check for the file it is never there.

The action always actually succeeds, but this behavior defeats a bit of scripting and automation I have built up around version control.

Does anyone know what is causing this issue and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that the .hg/wcache folder was owned by root.

So the somewhat obvious point in hindsight appears to be

If the error message mentions "permission denied" then check the permission of the folder in question.  In this case it was owned by root.  I was able to solve with

```
[.hg]$ sudo chown cgrandits wcache
```

where cgrandits is my user id. Obviously I need sudo ability to do this fix, but I need sudo ability to run the build automation scripts that got me into this in the first place.

I got into this situation because I use build automation scripts (that I admittedly don't fully understand) which setup a chroot environment and so must execute as root.  Sometimes these build automation scripts do mercurial commands.  If the wcache folder does not exist at the point the build automation script executing as root, then the wcache folder will get created, *but with owner as root*.  But if the wcache folder already exists, the hg actions will use it *as is*.  So whether this problem is ecountered depends on historical order of hg commands given directly on the command line and execution of certain build automation scripts.